# Mocha runs test from deleted spec

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, ts-node

I'm running tests with mocha on a node project in Visual Studio Code.  During some refactoring I renamed one of my test specs from `basic-heating-rule-spec.ts` to `rule-config-spec.ts`.

The refactored test is failing, not a big deal, but the error seems to indicate that the now deleted `basic-heating-rule-spec.ts` is still being run:

```
  49 passing (98ms)
  1 failing

  1) RuleConfig
       should load with valid data:
     Error: Config validation, cannot find timeOfDayConfig:hour and no default value supplied
      at getValue (src\config-validation.ts:52:15)
      at Function.getNumber (src\config-validation.ts:13:16)
      at new TimeOfDay (src\configuration\time-of-day.ts:32:53)
      at new RuleConfig (src\configuration\rule-config.ts:38:28)
      at Context.it (test\configuration\rule\basic-heating-rule-spec.ts:12:29)
```

It seems that the old spec is being cached somewhere.  I tried restarting VSCode and rebooting my machine but the non-existent test file continues to run.  Does anyone know where the file is being cached and how I can clear it?

I execute the tests with `npm run test` and my package.json contains this:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf lib",
    "lint": "tslint --force --format verbose \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run lint && echo Using TypeScript && tsc --version && tsc --pretty",
    "test": "npm run build && mocha --require ts-node/register --recursive \"test/**/*-spec.ts\""
},
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "include": ["index.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "test/**/*-spec.ts"],
}
```

And even more weird: the refactored `rule-config-spec.ts` contains `describe("RuleConfig"() =>...)` which shows up in the message above.  If I change this to `describe("RuleXXXConfig"() =>...)` then I get an error referencing the correct file:

```
  49 passing (130ms)
  1 failing

  1) RuleXXXConfig
       should load with valid data:
     Error: Config validation, cannot find timeOfDayConfig:hour and no default value supplied
      at getValue (src\config-validation.ts:52:15)
      at Function.getNumber (src\config-validation.ts:13:16)
      at new TimeOfDay (src\configuration\time-of-day.ts:32:53)
      at new RuleConfig (src\configuration\rule-config.ts:38:28)
      at Context.it (test\configuration\rule\rule-config-spec.ts:12:29)
```

If I change it back to `describe("RuleConfig"() =>...)` then I get old message that references the non-existent test file again:

```
  49 passing (102ms)
  1 failing

  1) RuleConfig
       should load with valid data:
     Error: Config validation, cannot find timeOfDayConfig:hour and no default value supplied
      at getValue (src\config-validation.ts:52:15)
      at Function.getNumber (src\config-validation.ts:13:16)
      at new TimeOfDay (src\configuration\time-of-day.ts:32:53)
      at new RuleConfig (src\configuration\rule-config.ts:38:28)
      at Context.it (test\configuration\rule\basic-heating-rule-spec.ts:12:29)
```

I am well and truly out of my depth by now: has anyone any idea WTF is going on here?

Comment: One idea I had is that there is an out-of-date source map being cached somewhere, perhaps by ts-node?  Mocha might be running the new js source but the console is displaying the wrong ts source.  Any idea how to investigate this further?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried deleting the node modules folder, then running npm install. Also try using terminal and not VS code integrated terminal.